Did any Early Christian exegesis interpret Ezekiel 29:3 to mean 'pharaoh made himself'?
In Latin Vulgate Old Testament Bible:
Ezekiel 29:3

Speak, and say: Thus saith the Lord God: Behold, I come against thee, Pharao king of Egypt, thou great dragon that liest in the midst of thy rivers, and sayest: The river is mine, and I made myself.

According to the interpretation, the pharaoh claimed to be the creator of himself (eg: divine). The question that I'd like to ask, isn't whether the Vulgate interpretation is valid or not.
It is whether any other ancient Christian writer might interpret it this way (that the pharaoh claimed that he created himself or thought of himself to be god).

As best I can determine, Eze 29:3 is never quoted nor referenced by any of the Ante-Nicaean fathers (ie, anybody writing before 325 AD) that is now extant.
However, many have commented since.
The understanding of this passage hinges on the implied pivot to metaphor, which makes the "great dragon/monster/crocodile" (grammatically speaking) in apposition to "Pharoah King of Egypt".
That is, the "great תַּנִּין " (tannin = serpent, dragon, sea monster, gen 1:21, Ex 7:9, 10, Deut 32:33, Neh 2:13, etc) is used as a metaphor in apposition for the Pharaoh.  Gill comments as follows:

the great dragon that lieth in the midst of his rivers; the chief
river of Egypt was the Nile, which opened in seven mouths or gates
into the sea, and out of which canals were made to water the whole
land; and which abounding with rivers and watery places, hence the
king of it is compared to a great fish, a dragon or whale, or rather a
crocodile, which was a fish very common, and almost peculiar to Egypt;
and with which the description here agrees, as Bochart observes; and
who also remarks that Pharaoh in the Arabic language signifies a
crocodile; and to which he may be compared for his cruel, voracious,
and mischievous nature; and is here represented as lying at ease, and
rolling himself in the enjoyment of his power, riches, and pleasures:
which hath said, my river is mine own, and I have made it for myself;
alluding to the river Nile, which his predecessors had by their wisdom
cut out into canals, for the better watering of the land; and which he
might have improved, so that it stood in no need of rain, nor of the
supplies of other countries, having a sufficiency from its own
product; though he chiefly designs his kingdom, which was his own, and
he had established it, and made himself great in it; for the last
clause may be rendered, either, "I have made it", as the Syriac
version, the river Nile, ascribing that to himself which belonged to
God; or, "I have made them", the rivers among whom he lay, as the
Septuagint and Arabic versions; or, "I have made myself", as the
Vulgate Latin version; that is, a great king. So the Targum,
"the kingdom is mine, and I have subdued it.''
Herodotus says of this king, that he was so lifted up with pride, and
so secure of his happy state, that he said there was no God could
deprive him of his kingdom (z). This proud tyrannical monarch was an
emblem of that beast that received his power from the dragon, and who
himself spake like one; of the whore of Babylon that sits upon many
waters, and boasts of her sovereignty and power, of her wealth and
riches, of her ease, peace, pleasure, prosperity, and settled estate,
Revelation 13:2.


the Vulgate wasn't created in time of the Ante-Nicaean fathers to consult it.

@DanFefferman - quite correct - I ignored that subtlety/contradiction in the OP's question.  In any case, he quoted English.

To clarify, the Vulgate is mistaken here. But as we shall see, it corrects itself in vs. 9. No modern translator renders the verse as meaning that the Pharaoh claimed to have created himself. The Church Fathers until near the end of the 4th century relied on the Septuagint, which is translated by Breton as reading:

3καὶ εἰπόν Τάδε λέγει Κύριος Ἰδοὺ ἐγὼ ἐπὶ Φαραώ, τὸν δράκοντα τὸν μέγαν τὸν ἐγκαθήμενον ἐν μέσῳ ποταμῶν αὐτοῦ, τὸν λέγοντα Ἐμοί εἰσιν οἱ ποταμοί, καὶ ἐγὼ ἐποίησα αὐτούς.


Thus saith the Lord; Behold, I am against Pharao, the great dragon
that lies in the midst of his rivers, that says, The rivers are mine,
and I made them.

Moreover, as mentioned above, the Old Vulgate corrects itself in vs. 9 saying:

et erit terra Aegypti in desertum et solitudinem et scient quia ego
Dominus eo quod dixerit fluvius meus est et ego feci
And the land of Egypt shall become a desert, and a wilderness: and
they shall know that I am the Lord, because thou hast said: The river
is mine, and I made it.

Conclusion: We can safely presume than the Church Fathers prior to 382 (when the Vulgate was created) referred to the Septuagint and understood that the Pharaoh claimed to have the rivers, not himself. Even those later Latin Fathers who used the Vulgate and ignored the Septuagint would understand the same from vs. 9 of the chapter in question.

Thanx for the clarification . If you have any Christian exegesis (not translation), that explain the passage of Ezekiel ( or any other passage in OT ) as a reference to pharaoh claiming to be God, please share it. thanx

I don't know of any... although it is true that the Pharaohs were thought to represents gods, especially Horus.
